# Unable to run ruby script over ssh into ec2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I'm working with ec2 instances and was trying to execute a ruby script on another instance after ssh to that instance. 
I have a ruby script which updates configuration files, so i need to run that script as super user. when i run the script manually on that instance, `sudo ruby recreate-532d01c.rb`, the error that comes is

```
sudo: ruby: command not found
```

Running simple scripts with no root permissions works, eg.`ruby file_1.rb`.

Using rvmsudo in place of sudo executes the script with warning,

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-111:~$ rvmsudo ruby recreate-82bb000012.rb 
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=0

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.
```

I tried to execute the below command from rails console of one of the instance to test and it fails to recognize ruby as command

```
1.9.3-p545 :002 > system("ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/own_key.pem ubuntu@**.***.***.** ruby execute-52d.rb")
bash: ruby: command not found
```

I tried with possible solutions over web, but could not resolve the issue. I have the same configuration running for one of my old aws acount, this is a newly created account. Not sure if this could be issue in any way as currently ec2 instances fall under vpc by default and have some changes after dec 2013

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with your VPC. So when you run your ruby script with `sudo` your environment that your `user` is using doesn't get set for Ruby.

Sounds like you may be using rvm and you probably set it up with a 'single user' config.

Try running as your `user`:

```
which ruby
```

and see where your ruby executable is located at. That's what you have to make sure that when your run your script as sudo it's available in the PATH.

Worst case you would have to reinstall rvm with multiuser config which should work when you run with `sudo`:

```
user$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

Comment: how can i check if ruby is available in path when i run the script after ssh, using command like this system("ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/own_key.pem ubuntu@54.***.***.** sudo ruby recreate-43dr5f.rb")

Comment: i just updated the question, you can check if it helps to explain my qsn better

Comment: ssh to your machine `ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/own_key.pem ubuntu@**.***.***.**` then once you are in the ssh session run `which ruby`

Comment: $which ruby  shows /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby

Comment: So you have a `user` installation of `rvm` that's why it doesn't run with `sudo`.  ssh to the machine in install `rvm` with multiuser support: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable`

Comment: even scripts without sudo don't run and throw errors, so is the installation type the issue?. I have installed  rvm for single user earlier and it has worked after ssh from another instance.